# C Recursive dynamic programming why they start from smallest value?

Tags: c

This is an algorithm problem solving. Making a number to 1 only using divide the number by 2 or 3 or subtract 1(minimum computation is needed). I made a solution like this, dynamic recursive form. I figured when I order number 10 to my program, computer would start the iteration from 10 to 1. But it actually worked from 1 to 10. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int memo[1000001];

int go(int n){
    if (n<=1) {
        memo[n] = 0;
        return memo[n];
    }
    int temp;

    if(memo[n]>0){ 
        printf("called n value is: %d\n", n);
        printf(" I found the value in previous memo[%d]=%d\n", n, memo[n]);
        return memo[n];
    }

    if (n>=2){
        memo[n] = go(n-1) +1;
        printf("n value is: %d\n", n);
        printf("processing minus one, and memo[%d]=memo[%d]+1: %d\n", n, n-1, memo[n]);
    }
    if(n%2==0){
        printf("temp devide 2 is called..\n");     
        temp = go(n/2) + 1;
        if (memo[n] > temp) {
            memo[n] =temp;
            printf("n value is: %d\n", n);
            printf("processing devide 2, and memo[%d]=memo[%d]: %d\n", n, n/2, memo[n]);
        } else {
            printf("memo is smaller or same!\n");
        }
    }
    if(n%3 ==0){
        printf("temp devide 3 is called..\n");     
        temp = go(n/3) + 1;
        if (memo[n] > temp){
            memo[n] = temp;
            printf("n value is: %d\n", n);
            printf("processing devide 3, and memo[%d]=memo[%d]: %d\n", n, n/3, memo[n]);
        } else {
            printf("memo is smaller or same!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("comparing...\n");
    printf("only recorded minimun value: memo[%d]=%d\n", n, memo[n]);
    return memo[n];
};

int main() {
    go(10);
}
```

```
Results:
n value is: 2
processing minus one, and memo[2]=memo[1]+1: 1
temp devide 2 is called..
memo is smaller or same!
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[2]=1
n value is: 3
processing minus one, and memo[3]=memo[2]+1: 2
temp devide 3 is called..
n value is: 3
processing devide 3, and memo[3]=memo[1]: 1
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[3]=1
n value is: 4
processing minus one, and memo[4]=memo[3]+1: 2
temp devide 2 is called..
called n value is: 2
 I found the value in previous memo[2]=1
memo is smaller or same!
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[4]=2
n value is: 5
processing minus one, and memo[5]=memo[4]+1: 3
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[5]=3
n value is: 6
processing minus one, and memo[6]=memo[5]+1: 4
temp devide 2 is called..
called n value is: 3
 I found the value in previous memo[3]=1
n value is: 6
processing devide 2, and memo[6]=memo[3]: 2
temp devide 3 is called..
called n value is: 2
 I found the value in previous memo[2]=1
memo is smaller or same!
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[6]=2
n value is: 7
processing minus one, and memo[7]=memo[6]+1: 3
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[7]=3
n value is: 8
processing minus one, and memo[8]=memo[7]+1: 4
temp devide 2 is called..
called n value is: 4
 I found the value in previous memo[4]=2
n value is: 8
processing devide 2, and memo[8]=memo[4]: 3
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[8]=3
n value is: 9
processing minus one, and memo[9]=memo[8]+1: 4
temp devide 3 is called..
called n value is: 3
 I found the value in previous memo[3]=1
n value is: 9
processing devide 3, and memo[9]=memo[3]: 2
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[9]=2
n value is: 10
processing minus one, and memo[10]=memo[9]+1: 3
temp devide 2 is called..
called n value is: 5
 I found the value in previous memo[5]=3
memo is smaller or same!
comparing...
only recorded minimun value: memo[10]=3
```

Comment: because of the recursive call in `if (n>=2){ memo[n] = go(n-1) +1;`

Comment: Some of your `printf`s are before the recursive call, and some are after the recursive call. A `printf` before a recursive call will be shown on the way down (as the recursion goes deeper). A `printf` after a recursive call will be shown on the way up (after the base case has been reached). You can reduce the confusion by putting `printf("called n value is: %d\n", n);` as the first line of your function, and remove the other `printf`s that print `n`.

Answer (score 1):

> I figured when I order number 10 to my program, computer would start the iteration from 10 to 1. But it actually worked from 1 to 10. Why?

your program start by 10 then 9 etc as you expected but because all these tests are false at the beginning (*memo* is a global variable initialized to 0) :

> ```
> if (n<=1) {
> ```

> ```
> if(memo[n]>0){
> ```

but

> ```
> if (n>=2){
> ```

is true so you do the recursive call

> ```
> memo[n] = go(n-1) +1;
> ```

and nothing else several times until `if (n<=1) {` becomes true